# Post and share on facebook on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my site i can give comment to any category or movie i just want
 when user rate any movie with comment that comment also post on
 FACEBOOK and share category data  on FACEBOOK.

if anybody have knowledge how to implement this please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Share This](http://www.sharethis.com/) its really simple to implement and works like a charm

Comment: but i want post facebook what ever i comment on my site.

Comment: try using something like this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

I've made a custom function.

Example:

function sharreBrag(){

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',

    link: app.home,
    picture: app.home + '/img/logo.png',
    name: 'TITLE!',
    caption: 'whatever you want',
    description: 'description'
};

function callback(response) {}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

};

The app.home is a variable with the link to your site.

Also you need to include the Facebook root into your footer.